# How to color background of Bootstrap row without column padding?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the background fit within bootstrap's column sizing, but still appear across the whole row. How could I achieve this?

I tried the following:

```css
.yourcontent {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.yourcontent [class^=col-] {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foobar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Barfoo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <div class="row yourcontent">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="">
            Foo
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="">
            Bar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="">
            Foobar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="">
            Barfoo
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnyk4su5/)

I want it to appear like this, except that the white space between the columns should be filled in with a color as well:

```css
.yourcontent {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foobar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Barfoo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Foo
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Bar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Foobar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Barfoo
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49zLrmcg/)

I would like the background to stretch for the whole row but not the padding-left of the first col-xs-* element and the padding-right of the last col-xs-* element within given row. Would anyone happen to know how to approach this?

Comment: Just use the `.no-gutters` class on your bootstrap row? - *Edit*, this only is for bootstrap 4 .. so create that class manualy.

Comment: You can add margin:0 0 5px to yourcontent class.
https://jsfiddle.net/hnyk4su5/1/

Comment: I was just about to say it was for Bootstrap 4 only @red I will check what it will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Bootstrap 4** you have the `.no-gutters` class. As you are using **Bootstrap 3** this class isn't included. However, you can easily create this class yourself. This will remove the *gutters* between the columns.

```css
.yourcontent {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

/* 
  Optional, to fix to width of the row 
*/
.row.no-gutters {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}


.row.no-gutters > [class^="col-"] {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foo</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Foobar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Barfoo</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Foo
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Bar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Foobar
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <div class="yourcontent">
            Barfoo
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the `.no-gutters` hint, works great in BS4.